# Can I push sub branch if the branch hasn't been merged yet?

Tags: git

We work the following way. I create separate branch for every issue and when the issue is done I push it to remote repo. I mean, I do

```
git branch issueXXX
git checkout issueXXX
//commits
git push origin issueXXX
```

After that team leader merges my branch to master.

Now I have a problem - I pushed the last issue, but team leader hasn't merged it to master yet and I have no idea when he will do it. However, my next issue is linked to the previous one. What should I do this way? I thought about creating sub branch from `issueXXX` and push it separately to remote, but I don't know if it possible as my previous issue hasn't been merged yet.

Could anyone say if is it possible or I should do something different (I just learn git)?

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with doing this AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can branch off `issueXXX` and push separately.

You'll now have two PRs. The latest will include the commits that already exist in the branch `issueXXX`. Once this branch is merged, the other PR will be left with the diff commits.

Comment: `Once this branch is merged` do you mean `Once branch issueXXX is merged`?

Comment: Yes, the one you branched from.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

The one you are leaning to - creating another feature branch from your already existing one is a valid strategy. You should not worry that you feature branch is not merged into master. Just because your feature hasn't been merged, doesn't mean you can't continue playing around with your local branches, creating new ones, expanding them, etc.

If you decide to do that, the following will *most likely* happen. You'll create a sub-feature branch from `issueXXX`, let's call it `afterXXXcomesYYY`. Work on it, make commits, etc. Then, when your lead merges your `issueXXX` you can do the following things:

1) Pull your new master (with the new feature in it), create a branch from the latest master called `issueYYY`, cherry-pick your commits from `afterXXXcomesYYY` and continue your development/creating more PRs.

2) You can just continue your work on `afterXXXcomesYYY` and at some point push it for a PR.

Comment: Or, instead of cherry-picking, you could pull the new master, rename `afterXXXcomesYYY` to `issueXXX`, and rebase off of master.